# RTMP FFmpeg muxing example

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, youtube, rtmp

I'm trying to use [the FFmpeg muxing example](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/muxing.c) to send content using RTMP.
When modifying the example to send something to a youtube channel, the live result isn't right:

```c
    av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_DEBUG);
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&oc, NULL, "flv", "rtmp://x.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/KEY");
```

Log seems fine :

```sh
[flv @ 0000016CDFB97640] intra_quant_bias = 0 inter_quant_bias = -64
[SWR @ 0000016CDFBD5140] Using s16p internally between filters
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://x.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/KEY':
  Stream #0:0, 0, 1/30: Video: flv1, 1 reference frame, yuv420p, 256x144 (0x0), 0/1, q=2-31, 400 kb/s, 30 tbn
  Stream #0:1, 0, 1/44100: Audio: adpcm_swf, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 352 kb/s
[rtmp @ 0000016CDFB63300] No default whitelist set
[tcp @ 0000016CDFB7E780] No default whitelist set
[tcp @ 0000016CDFB7E780] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 0000016CDFB7E780] Address 142.250.178.172 port 1935
[tcp @ 0000016CDFB7E780] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 0000016CDFB7E780] Address 142.250.178.172 port 1935
[tcp @ 0000016CDFB7E780] Starting connection attempt to 142.250.178.172 port 1935
[tcp @ 0000016CDFB7E780] Successfully connected to 142.250.178.172 port 1935
[rtmp @ 0000016CDFB63300] Handshaking...
[rtmp @ 0000016CDFB63300] Type answer 3
[rtmp @ 0000016CDFB63300] Server version 4.0.0.1
[rtmp @ 0000016CDFB63300] Proto = rtmp, path = /live2/KEY, app = live2, fname = KEY
[rtmp @ 0000016CDFB63300] Window acknowledgement size = 2500000
[rtmp @ 0000016CDFB63300] Max sent, unacked = 57000000
[rtmp @ 0000016CDFB63300] Releasing stream...
[rtmp @ 0000016CDFB63300] FCPublish stream...
[rtmp @ 0000016CDFB63300] Creating stream...
[rtmp @ 0000016CDFB63300] Sending publish command for 'KEY'
```

On youtube, the issue is as follow:
after 1min20seconds of streaming, the length of the timeline is of 10min or so, as you can see [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rmdlYwkqHfzYkkGoL-W6Ocku9aTUk0da/view?usp=sharing).

My guess is that youtube is receiving more than 25 frames per seconds, and doesn't discard them.
Therefore the timeline grows creating a video with all the frames 1/25 of a second appart, which doesn't correspond to the actual length of streaming.
I can provide the PTS DTS if needed.

I'm not sure how to make the AVCodeccontext wait.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://github.com/leixiaohua1020/simplest_ffmpeg_streamer/blob/master/simplest_ffmpeg_streamer/simplest_ffmpeg_streamer.cpp#L162) rtmp ffmpeg example which is a little old; i used the `av_usleep` :

```cpp
// inside write_frame
              

        /* rescale output packet timestamp values from codec to stream timebase */
        av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, c->time_base, st->time_base);
        pkt->stream_index = st->index;



        AVRational time_base = st->time_base;
        AVRational time_base_q = { 1,AV_TIME_BASE };
        int64_t pts_time = av_rescale_q(pkt->dts, time_base, time_base_q);
        int64_t now_time = av_gettime() - start_time;
        if (pts_time > now_time) {
            av_usleep(pts_time - now_time);
        }


        /* Write the compressed frame to the media file. */
        log_packet(fmt_ctx, pkt);
```